# Outputting html form data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

**HTML Code:**

```html
<form class="form-inline signup" role="form" action="script.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" > 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Get notified!</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST["email"]))
    file_put_contents("emails.txt", file_get_contents("emails.txt") . "\n" . $_POST["email"]);
?>
```

I tried several methods before asking here but none works. 
When the button is click it loads the php code and shows a blank page on the browser.

Comment: Hard to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: use name attribute and form method

Comment: You need to set an action for the form.

Comment: This isn't a free coding service, so you'll have to try some yourself first. Which shouldn't be hard, there are many guides you'll find just by Google your request. You can post here it you have a specific issue you can't solve.

Comment: I want to save the emails people input their into a .txt file in the server or maybe email the input to me. Any php codes that can help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a **lot of things** before you can start.

1. Set the `action` attribute of the form to a `.php` file.

   ```
   <form class="form-inline signup" role="form" action="write.php" method="post">
   ```
2. Give a `name` attribute to the `<input />` element.

   ```
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
          placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" />
   ```
3. In the `write.php` (or whatever PHP file you use), **actually write** to the file.

   ```
   <?php
     if (!empty($_POST["email"]))
       file_put_contents("emails.txt", file_get_contents("emails.txt") . "\n" . $_POST["email"]);
   ?>
   ```
4. Last but not least, please **run this on the server** and not in browser:

   ```
   http://localhost/file.php
   ```

Comment: @DeepKakkar Yea. Right.

Comment: @devpro 100s of people making that mistake dude. So frustrating. `:(`

Comment: When the get notified is clicked it goes straight to the php file and nothing is added to the .txt file. Btw running on a server not in browser..

Comment: @MohamedArham Have you changed the form as I have given you? Can you please edit your question and add the new form source code? Give the source of both the form and the PHP file please.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have edited the question, can you please go through it ! thank you for your help !

Comment: @MohamedArham Checking it.

Comment: @MohamedArham Few questions. **1.** Are both the files, the form file and the PHP file are in the same directory? **2.** Are you getting a blank page after clicking on the button? **3.** Did you create the file `emails.txt` before?

Comment: @PraveenKumar
1. Yes they are in the same directory. 
2. Yes after clicking the button
3. Yes I created the emails.txt

Comment: @MohamedArham Nice. What do you see when you open the `emails.txt`?

Comment: @MohamedArham I am gonna check it from my end, from my server.

Comment: @MohamedArham No issues here. Works fine. Check the permissions, enable the errors? See the log file?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry for the late reply. I set all the permissions and still when the button is clicked it shows a blank page. I have the index.html in a subdir and all the scripts in a folder inside it. The write.php is also located in the subdir. Can't seem to get it right.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have been going through the code by letter for the past 3 hours. Cant find anything wrong ! I am going mad over here !

Comment: @MohamedArham Ha ha... I asked you something. See the logs?

Comment: @MohamedArham Yes yes, buddy.

Comment: @MohamedArham Wow. :D Ha ha. I don't know what to say! This is the best I could think of. Try spinning up a Cloud9 IDE and let's work together! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar created IDE and added you with r/w permissions. Check ;)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Damn fixed it! Phew... some issues with permissions. I wasted around 3 hours.............

Comment: @MohamedArham I said you right. Permissions!!! `:P` Now go enjoy the day. Sleep well. `:D`